# ImageMagick convert -crop returns the same image

Tags: linux, image, imagemagick, crop

I am having a really odd behavior when using **convert -crop** feature. When invoking a fairly simple command like the following:

```
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x369+928+519 /tmpdir/heading.jpg /tmpdir/crop.jpg
```

crop.jpg is the same output as heading.jpg.

By doing something like 100 tests on different samples, I found out it doesn't happen on a regular basis and I couldn't find the reason why.

The original image (heading.jpg) is a simple image file, 1920x1080px in resolution. I made the following tests. **works** are the commands that are executed with success, **fails** are the commands where crop.jpg are perfect clones of heading.jpg.

```
/usr/bin/convert -crop 100x100 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
/usr/bin/convert -crop 100x200 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
/usr/bin/convert -crop 200x100 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x200 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x300 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x369 heading.jpg crop.jpg   fails
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x368 heading.jpg crop.jpg   fails
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x367 heading.jpg crop.jpg   fails
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x366 heading.jpg crop.jpg   fails
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x365 heading.jpg crop.jpg   fails
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x364 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x363 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x362 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x361 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
/usr/bin/convert -crop 652x360 heading.jpg crop.jpg   works
```

I tested this with different files format (but I mostly work with jpg files) and resolutions, and can't predict - and therefore find a solution - to the issue.

The issue happens on a CentOS 7.7.1908.

Also tried upgrading ImageMagick, so I have the very same behavior on:

- 6.7.8.9 (yum package ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-18.el7.x86_64)
- 7.0.10-1 (rpm from ImageMagick website)

Does anybody have any hint?

Comment: Strange. Please eit into your question: Did you get any height above ×364 to work?

Comment: Try using the updated syntax, where the **order** is important `convert INPUT -crop ... OUTPUT` Try also *"repaging"* before and after processing `convert INPUT +repage -crop ... +repage OUTPUT`

Comment: I get a similar result (output=input) if the geometry is invalid (crop rectangle not entirely within image area). But there are error messages. Are you discarding stderr?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the input image, heading.jpg?

Comment: @fmw42 1920x1080, mentioned in the post...

Comment: I have tried updating the order of the INPUT file, it gave me the very same result on 6.X, but seems to be working on 7.x.

I am not making some further test, because it appears that we have some scenario where the issue persists. I will follow up this asap.

Comment: ImageMagick 6.7.8.9 is known to be buggy. Perhaps you need to upgrade your IM 6 version.